# What dose mean by "window.scrollY > 0"

Tags: javascript, dom-events, jsdom

```
window.addEventListener("scroll",()=>{
const header = document.querySelector("header");
header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
})
```

I know about .toggle() method but not so clearly. Would some one please explain about toggle() and window.scrollY?

Comment: Did you consider [looking it up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY)?

Comment: when your scrollBar is at the top its position is 0 & when you scrollDown it increases

Comment: to be honest, since `toggle()` here is always used with the `force` parameter, it will only add the class OR it will only remove the class, depending on `(window.scrollY > 0)` - it will never actually switch the class based on class presence itself

Comment: what I mean is, that code is basically `if (window.scrollY > 0) { header.classList.add('sticky'); } else { header.classList.remove('sticky'); }`

Comment: it will actually toggle when the ScrollY is 0.but we would not be able to see any difference. But it will definitely toggle...

Comment: @UmairFarooq in reality it doesn't toggle, when `force` is false (scrollY = 0), it will only remove the class if present (if class is not present, it will not add it). I admit this is the first time I see `toggle()` used with the second parameter set.

Comment: @GrafiCode check the answer now.it toggles

Answer (score 1):

Scroll Down. scrollY property of the Window interface returns the number of pixels that the document is currently scrolled vertically.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
  document.querySelector("h1").textContent = this.scrollY;
  document.querySelector("h2").textContent = ("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
})
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 400vh;
}

h1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

h2 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
}
```

```html
<h1>0</h1>
<h2></h2>
```